# Sound out of sync after merging multiple mp4 files with Avidemux

Tags: video-editing, mp4, video-conversion, lossless, avidemux

I am trying to join (merge) two or more .mp4 files together, without re-encoding.

Here is what I did:

1. Started Avidemux 2.5.5.
2. With File->Open, selected Input1.mp4.
3. I received this message - "H.264 detected. If the file is using B-frames as reference it can lead to a crash or stuttering. Avidemux can use another mode which is safe but YOU WILL LOOSE SOME FRAME ACCURACY. Do you want to use that mode?". I chose "No".
4. With File->Append, selected Input2.mp4.
5. I received the same "H.264 detected" message again and chose "No".
6. Selected the Format to MP4 (from AVI).
7. Saved the output file (called Output.mp4) with File->Save->Save Video.

Unfortunately, when I play the Output.mp4 video in VLC, the sound is out of sync with the second video. How can I correct this?

Comment: I've tried the new version - 2.5.6, but still have the same sound sync problem.

Comment: Would [Free AVI/MPEG/WMV/MP4/FLV Video Joiner](http://www.freeaudiovideosoft.com/free-avi-mpeg-wmv-mp4-flv-video-joiner/index.html) be a good alternative to use?

Comment: How is it out of sync, sound first or video first?

Answer (score 1):

I had horribly garbled audio when trying to combine 5 different clips into one. They were all different audio and video formats and, no matter what I tried, it turned into a garbled mess when trying to combine more than a couple clips at once.

The solution was to convert each and every clip individually to **PCM raw audio** with the same frequency sampling (44.1k) and remixed to stereo sound. Then I could easily combine the clips with raw audio and everything worked perfectly. I then re-encoded the combination to vorbis and it was still in sync.

Answer (score 0):

I have had much better results joining multiple video files using mkvmerge from the [MKVToolNix](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/downloads.html) tools.

Just download and install the windows installer from [here](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/downloads.html#windows). Then run the mkvmerge GUI, add the first file, and then use the append button to add the additional files. This does give you an mkv file instead of an mp4 file, but VLC should be able to play that without any trouble. Also, there is no re-encoding going on, only re-muxing.

Comment: Is there any similar free software that works with MP4 files?  Although VLC does a great job at playing lots of different formats, I'd prefer to stick with MP4 for consistency.

Comment: You're in luck, it looks like [mp4box](http://gpac.wp.institut-telecom.fr/mp4box/mp4box-documentation/#split_concat) supports concatenating mp4 files. I have not really used mp4box, so I can't say how well it work. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Although I haven't tried mp4box myself, some [comments on the GUI](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/My-MP4Box-GUI) did mention sound sync issues.

Comment: I saw that too. But, there are a large number of variables when it comes to concatenating media files together (codec used for the audio/video, multiple tracks, subtitles, etc.). The comment I saw that mentions sync issues was using the trimming feature, not concatenation. The only way to be sure is to try it for yourself.